# difference between Source code parser and Grammar parser

Tags: parser-generator

I have been trying to research on source  code parser and often i would find people talking about parsing grammar.

so I was wondering what's the difference between a source code parser and grammar parser, are they the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "source code parser"  by itself is clear enough:  this is a mechanism that parses source text, using either a parser-generator engine based off of a formal grammar or some kind of hand-coded (typically recursive descent) parser derived from the grammar informally.  It is unclear what the result of a "source code parser" is from just the phrase; it might just be "yes, that's valid syntax", more usually "produces a parse or abstract syntax tree", or it might be (sloppily) "full abstract syntax tree plus symbol table plus control and dataflow analyses".

The phrase "grammar parser" is not one I encounter much (and I work a lot in this field).  It is likely something garbled from some other source.  In the absence of a widely known definition, one would guess that this means a)  a "source code parser" driven by a parser generator engine from a formal grammar, or b) a "source code parser" which parses a grammar (which is a kind of source code, too), as an analog to the phrase "Fortran parser".   For the latter I would tend to write "parser for a grammar" to avoid confusion, although "Fortran parser" is pretty clear.

You used a third term, "parsing grammar" which I also don't encounter much.  This is likely to mean b) in the above paragraph.

Where did your terms come from?

Answer (score 1):

[Bison is a general purpose parser generator that converts a grammar description for an LALR(1) context-free grammar into a C program to parse that grammar.](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bison.htm)

This kind of talk is not correct.  There are 3 mistakes in this.  It should read:

Bison is a general purpose parser generator that

1. reads a BNF grammar, which defines the syntax of a context-free language,
2. does an LALR(1) analysis and conflict resolution, and
3. outputs a C program that reads input written in the language whose syntax 
   is defined in the BNF grammar.

My intent is not to criticize, but to get people to use the correct terminology.
There is already enough misunderstanding in this subject.

Comment: People manage to the munge the vocabulary pretty badly at times, right.